# Identity Server 4 Refresh Token Expiration Not Working

Tags: jwt, identityserver4, refresh-token

I have created a client in Identity Server 4 auth server and have set the following token properties:

```
 var idsClient = new Client
                {
                    ClientName = parsedResult.Name,
                    ClientId = parsedResult.ClientId,
                    RequireConsent = false,
                    RequirePkce = false,
                    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                    RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.OneTimeOnly,
                    RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Sliding,
                    AccessTokenLifetime = 7200, //2 hours
                    AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime = 2592000, //30 days
                    SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime = 1296000 //15 days
                };
```

When I request an access token it's expiration is set to 2 hours and a refresh token value is returned. When I request a refresh token the expiration is still set at 2 hours instead of 15 days.

Here are picks for token and refresh token requests:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not *request* a refresh token but you *use* the refresh token to request an *access token*.

Since you configured `TokenUsage.OneTimeOnly`, each succesful response will return two tokens:

- Access Token
- Refresh Token

I'm not sure which token you expect to be set to 15 days, but the Access Token should always have a lifetime of two hours, in this case.

Comment: You can't. The expiration of the access token will always be two hours.

Comment: So I get the terminology and that's what I'm doing... I am using the refresh token to request an access token and that access token is always set to expire in 2 hours. How can I get the access token from a refresh token request to expire in 15 days? Does the refresh token last for 15 days... meaning it will request access token for 15 days until it expires? Which in turn every access token expires in 2 hours?

Also, I have also tried RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.ReUse with the same results.

Comment: Ok, I think I got now. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can use the access token for 15 days and at most for 30 days (absolute lifetime of the refresh token). Then the user has to login again.